# Как правильно переместить ту сумму чуть выше (ближе к слову "Корзина")?

Tags: html, css

Вот код:

```css
@import url(reset.css);
 .header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
body background {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.header-up a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#header1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header2-up {
  background-color: #285023;
}
.header-up img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
#login {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#signin {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#logo {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#tovari {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#korzina {
  float: right;
  width: 101px;
}
#korzina2 {
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
}
#summa {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Мой сайт</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header2-up">
    <div class="header-up">
      <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="shesterenka"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
      <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
      <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
      <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerlogo">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/> от производителей</span>
    <span id="vremya"><span>Пн-Вс:10:00-21:00</span>
    <br/><span>+7 (495) 989-72-68</span></span>
    <a href="#" id="zakazat">
      <img src="images/zakazat.png"></img>
    </a>
    <div id="korzina">
      <img src="images/korzina.png" />
      <a href="#" id="korzina2">Корзина<br/></a>
      <h6 id="summa">35 560 р.</h6>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

я добавил `position: relative; margin-top: -5px;`

```
#summa {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```css
@import url(reset.css);
 .header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
body background {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.header-up a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#header1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header2-up {
  background-color: #285023;
}
.header-up img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
#login {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#signin {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#logo {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#tovari {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#korzina {
  float: right;
  width: 101px;
}
#korzina2 {
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
}
#summa {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Мой сайт</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header2-up">
    <div class="header-up">
      <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="shesterenka"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
      <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
      <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
      <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerlogo">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/> от производителей</span>
    <span id="vremya"><span>Пн-Вс:10:00-21:00</span>
    <br/><span>+7 (495) 989-72-68</span></span>
    <a href="#" id="zakazat">
      <img src="images/zakazat.png"></img>
    </a>
    <div id="korzina">
      <img src="images/korzina.png" />
      <a href="#" id="korzina2">Корзина<br/></a>
      <h6 id="summa">35 560 р.</h6>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А можете также добавить пример кода для большей наглядности вашего ответа?

Comment: я добавил код  ..